# Primefaces inplace calling method before getting into input mode

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

Is it possible to call a bean method when clicking on the inplace field? In my example I want to click on the outputlabel and call a method before getting to the input mode.
Tried many different things with p:ajax but nothing worked. Using PF 5 and JSF 2.2 on a Wildfly server.

```
           <p:inplace >
              <f:facet name="output">
                 <p:outputLabel value="#{elm.text}" />
              </f:facet>
              <f:facet name="input">
                 <p:inputText value="#{elm.text}" />
              </f:facet>
           </p:inplace>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code.

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{elm.text}">
  <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.method}" />
</p:outputLabel>
```

It worked for me.